# Vanilla JS left to right toggle animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I am a newbie to code and I am learning vanilla JS. I created this drawer navigation with a circle that moves from left tor right, but there is an issue. I uploaded the current state here: http://setup.industries/masquarade/

The issue that gets me stuck:

- The first click on the hamburger nav icon doesn't open the drawer and the animation is switched. I suspect the problem to be in the if(open) as the open var doesn't truly capture the toggle state with `open = header.style.width == '0%'` After the initial bug, it works fine. A real head scratcher for me.

If you have other tips for better code, or point out my bad practices, I'd be happy to learn.

--

Edit 1: I have added the full code to this question. I am not sure how I can make the ellipse visible, i linked directly to hosted url.

```js
      // open sidenav //

      function openNav() {
        let header = document.getElementById("header");
        let open = header.style.width == '0%'
        let width = document.body.clientWidth;
        var ellipse = document.getElementById("ellipse");

        function moveEllipseRight() {
          ellipse.animate([
          // keyframes
          { transform: 'translateX(0px)' },
          { transform:  'translateX('+ width + 'px)' }
        ], {
          // timing options
          duration: 500,
          iterations: 1,
          easing: 'ease-in-out',
          fill: 'forwards'
        });}

        function moveEllipseLeft() {
          ellipse.animate([
          // keyframes
          { transform:  'translateX('+ width + 'px)' },
          { transform: 'translateX(0px)' }
        ], {
          // timing options
          duration: 500,
          iterations: 1,
          easing: 'ease-in-out',
          fill: 'forwards'
        });}

        // open sidenav //

        if (open) {
            header.style.width = "100%";
             moveEllipseRight();
        } else {
             header.style.width = '0%';
             moveEllipseLeft();
           }
         }

//  if (open) {
//   ellipse.classList.remove("ellipse_left");
//    ellipse.classList.add("ellipse_right");
//  } else {
//    ellipse.classList.remove("ellipse_right");
//    ellipse.classList.add("ellipse_left");
//  }

//  let ellipse = document.getElementById("ellipse");
//  let pos = 0;
//  let id = setInterval(frame, 5);


 //  function myMove() {
 //    console.log('Hello')
 //    var ellipse = document.getElementById("ellipse");
 //    var pos = -200;
 //    var id = setInterval(frame, 1);
 //    let width = document.body.clientWidth; // - $('#mydiv').width();
 //
 //        function frame() {
 //          if (pos == width - 200) {
 //            clearInterval(id);
 //          } else {
 //            pos++;
 //            ellipse.style.left = pos + "px";
 //          }
 //        }
 //    }


// information tabs //

function openTab(evt, tab) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(tab).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
html, body {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
body {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 1.4em;
}

a {
  color: white;
}

.clear {
  clear: both; float: none; height: 40px;
}

/* Ellipse */

#ellipse {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  z-index:99;
  animation: 3s linear 0s slide 1;
  left: -200px;
}

/*
.ellipse_left {left: -200px;}
.ellipse_right {right: -200px;}
*/


/* Masquarede Logo */

img.masquarade_events {
  opacity: 0.3;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}

img.masquarade_events:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}


/* Content */

.content {
  margin: 150px 0 0 300px;
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .content {
    margin: 150px 0 0 0;
    width: 700px;
    height: 400px;
  }
}

.date {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.location {
}

ul.lineup {
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

ul.lineup li {
  margin-right: 50px;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  float: left;
}


/* Buttons */

a.button {
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 10px 50px 10px 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 200px;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

a.white {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}

a.white:hover {
  color: white;
  background: #D90E46;
}

a.black {
  border: 2px white solid;
  color: white;
}

a.black:hover {
  border: 2px #FCF454 solid;
  color: #FCF454;
}

/* Header  */

header {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Navigation  */

header nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  right:300px;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 1em;
}

nav ul li{
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

nav ul li:hover{
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
}

li.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul li:first-child{
/*  border-top: 1px solid white;*/
}

nav ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul h2{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
}

/* Header Icon */

img.icon {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  top:60px;
  right:70px;
}

/* Display */

.display {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  right:750px;
}

.display p {
  margin:0 30px 30px 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- SETUP Industries - FUNCTIONAL DESIGN -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/> -->


    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/style.css" />
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Heebo:400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="assets/javascript.js"></script>


    <title>Masquarade Classix 2019</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <!-- Navigation -->

    <!-- Icon -->
    <img onclick="openNav()"id="icon" src="http://setup.industries/masquarade/assets/icon.svg" class="icon" width="40" alt="Expand Navigation" />
    <header id="header">

      <nav>
        <ul>
          <h2>Information</h2>
          <li class="tablinks" onmouseover="openTab(event, 'Tickets')"><a href="#">Tickets and pricing </a></li>
          <li class="tablinks" onmouseover="openTab(event, 'Location')"><a href="#">Location</a></li>
          <li class="tablinks" onmouseover="openTab(event, 'Transportation')"><a href="#">Transportation</a></li>
          <li class="tablinks" onmouseover="openTab(event, 'Amenities')"><a href="#">Ameneties</li>
          <li class="tablinks" onmouseover="openTab(event, 'HouseRules')"><a href="#">House rules</a></li>
          <li class="tablinks" onmouseover="openTab(event, 'TermsAndConditions')"><a href="#">Terms and conditions</a></li>
          <li class="tablinks" onmouseover="openTab(event, 'Contact')"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="tablinks" onmouseover="openTab(event, 'Partners')"><a href="#">Partners</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>


<div class="display">


      <div id="Tickets" class="tabcontent">
          <h2>Tickets and pricing</h2>
          <p>Saturday day tickets cost 45 EUR incl. service costs and 21% BTW. You can buy tickets online via the button below or at one of the resellers listed below.</p>
          <a href="#" class="button white">Buy Tickets</a>
          <br><br>
          <p style="font-size:0.8em;"> <strong>Paperpoint</strong><br>
            3930 Hamont-achel<br><br>
            <strong>Dag en nachtwinkel </strong><br>
            3900 Overpelt<br><br>
            <strong>VDM bvba, Q8 tankstation</strong> <br>
            Peer<br><br>
            <strong>Frituur De Kromme Draai</strong> <br>
            Eksel<br><br>
            <strong>’t frituurke</strong> <br>
            Haag 22, 3910 Achel<br></p>
      </div>

      <div id="Location" class="tabcontent">
          <h2>Location</h2>
      </div>

      <div id="Transportation" class="tabcontent">
          <h2>Transportation</h2>
      </div>

      <div id="Amenities" class="tabcontent">
          <h2>Amenities</h2>
      </div>

      <div id="HouseRules" class="tabcontent">
          <h2>House Rules</h2>
      </div>

      <div id="TermsAndConditions" class="tabcontent">
          <h2>Terms And Conditions</h2>
      </div>

      <div id="Contact" class="tabcontent">
          <h2>Contact</h2>
      </div>

      <div id="Partners" class="tabcontent">
          <h2>Partners</h2>
      </div>



</div>


    </header>
  <!-- Navigation End -->
<div class="container">
    <div id="ellipse" class="ellipse_left">
      <img src="assets/ellipse.svg" alt="ellipse" width="400" height="400"/>
    </div>
    <img class="masquarade_events" src="assets/masquarade_events.png" alt="Masquarade Events" width="125" height=""/>
<div class="content">

    <p class="date">25 mei 2019</p>
    <p class="location">Hennemeeuwis Neerpelt</p>
    <h1>Masquarade Classix </h1>
    <ul class="lineup">
        <li>Nina Kraviz</li>
        <li>Recondite</li>
        <li>Mind Against</li>
        <li>Âme</li>
        <li>Vince Watson</li>
        <li>Kölsch</li>
        <li>Rodriguez Jr. </li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
<div class="clear"></div>

    <a href="#" class="button white">Buy Tickets</a>
    <a href="#" class="button black">More Information</a>

</div>
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add your full code, including HTML and CSS, to the question.

Comment: You have a promise problem, animation are always asynchrone

Comment: @FZs onclick="openNav()" on the hamburger menu icon.

Comment: Instead of checking if the width is `0%`, Personally, I would just add a class "open" on the element. Then check if element's classes includes open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value for element.style is set by using either javascript or inline style attribute, css will not set the value for you. Therefore, if you are using a css to style the header's width, the value for `header.style.width` would be an empty string initially, making the expression `header.style.width == '0%'` to be falsy.

You can add a `console.log(document.getElementById('header').style.width)` to check the value yourself.

As a result, the first time you click the hamburger, the else block in the conditional will always be ran.

After the first time you click the hamburger, `document.getElementById('header').style.width` is now being set through javascript, so the subsequent clicks will behave as expected.

To solve the problem, you can either use an inline style attribute to style your header's  width, or you can get the style using javascript with

```
const headerWidth = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('header')).width;
const open = headerWidth === '0px' || headerWidth === '0%';
```

Answer (score 1):

You had your open logic reversed. Simply changing the order of 100% / 0% fixes this.

Improvement tips:

1. checking the elements state by using a class instead of the actual CSS. (Adding an `open` class to the element when it is open, and removing it when it is not open)
2. By doing the above, you can move the manipulation of width to the CSS class `open`: `header.open {width: 100%}`
3. By using "`" and encapsulating your variables in `${}` you can get rid of many "+" like so: { transform:  `translateX(${width}px)` }

Can be seen in the snippet:

```js
// open sidenav //

      function openNav() {
        let header = document.getElementById("header");
        let open = header.className.includes('open')
        let width = document.body.clientWidth;
        var ellipse = document.getElementById("ellipse");

        function moveEllipseRight() {
          ellipse.animate([
          // keyframes
          { transform: 'translateX(0)' },
          { transform:  `translateX(${width}px)` }
        ], {
          // timing options
          duration: 500,
          iterations: 1,
          easing: 'ease-in-out',
          fill: 'forwards'
        });}

        function moveEllipseLeft() {
          ellipse.animate([
          // keyframes
          { transform:  `translateX(${width}px)` },
          { transform: 'translateX(0)' }
        ], {
          // timing options
          duration: 500,
          iterations: 1,
          easing: 'ease-in-out',
          fill: 'forwards'
        });}

        // open sidenav //

        if (open) {
             moveEllipseLeft();
             header.classList.remove("open");
        } else {
             moveEllipseRight();
             header.classList.add("open");
           }
         }


// information tabs //

function openTab(evt, tab) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(tab).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
html, body {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
body {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 1.4em;
}

a {
  color: white;
}

.clear {
  clear: both; float: none; height: 40px;
}

/* Ellipse */

#ellipse {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  z-index:99;
  animation: 3s linear 0s slide 1;
  left: -200px;
}

/*
.ellipse_left {left: -200px;}
.ellipse_right {right: -200px;}
*/


/* Masquarede Logo */

img.masquarade_events {
  opacity: 0.3;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}

img.masquarade_events:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}


/* Content */

.content {
  margin: 150px 0 0 300px;
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .content {
    margin: 150px 0 0 0;
    width: 700px;
    height: 400px;
  }
}

.date {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.location {
}

ul.lineup {
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

ul.lineup li {
  margin-right: 50px;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  float: left;
}


/* Buttons */

a.button {
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 10px 50px 10px 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 200px;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

a.white {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}

a.white:hover {
  color: white;
  background: #D90E46;
}

a.black {
  border: 2px white solid;
  color: white;
}

a.black:hover {
  border: 2px #FCF454 solid;
  color: #FCF454;
}

/* Header  */

header {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
/* Header animation css  */
header.open {
  width: 100%;
}

/* Navigation  */

header nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  right:300px;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 1em;
}

nav ul li{
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

nav ul li:hover{
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
}

li.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul li:first-child{
/*  border-top: 1px solid white;*/
}

nav ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul h2{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
}

/* Header Icon */

img.icon {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  top:60px;
  right:70px;
}

/* Display */

.display {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  right:750px;
}

.display p {
  margin:0 30px 30px 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- SETUP Industries - FUNCTIONAL DESIGN -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/> -->


    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/style.css" />
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Heebo:400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="assets/javascript.js"></script>


    <title>Masquarade Classix 2019</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <!-- Navigation -->

    <!-- Icon -->
    <img onclick="openNav()"id="icon" src="http://setup.industries/masquarade/assets/icon.svg" class="icon" width="40" alt="Expand Navigation" />
    <header id="header">

      <nav>
        <ul>
          <h2>Information</h2>
          <li class="tablinks" onmouseover="openTab(event, 'Tickets')"><a href="#">Tickets and pricing </a></li>
          <li class="tablinks" onmouseover="openTab(event, 'Location')"><a href="#">Location</a></li>
          <li class="tablinks" onmouseover="openTab(event, 'Transportation')"><a href="#">Transportation</a></li>
          <li class="tablinks" onmouseover="openTab(event, 'Amenities')"><a href="#">Ameneties</li>
          <li class="tablinks" onmouseover="openTab(event, 'HouseRules')"><a href="#">House rules</a></li>
          <li class="tablinks" onmouseover="openTab(event, 'TermsAndConditions')"><a href="#">Terms and conditions</a></li>
          <li class="tablinks" onmouseover="openTab(event, 'Contact')"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="tablinks" onmouseover="openTab(event, 'Partners')"><a href="#">Partners</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>


<div class="display">


      <div id="Tickets" class="tabcontent">
          <h2>Tickets and pricing</h2>
          <p>Saturday day tickets cost 45 EUR incl. service costs and 21% BTW. You can buy tickets online via the button below or at one of the resellers listed below.</p>
          <a href="#" class="button white">Buy Tickets</a>
          <br><br>
          <p style="font-size:0.8em;"> <strong>Paperpoint</strong><br>
            3930 Hamont-achel<br><br>
            <strong>Dag en nachtwinkel </strong><br>
            3900 Overpelt<br><br>
            <strong>VDM bvba, Q8 tankstation</strong> <br>
            Peer<br><br>
            <strong>Frituur De Kromme Draai</strong> <br>
            Eksel<br><br>
            <strong>’t frituurke</strong> <br>
            Haag 22, 3910 Achel<br></p>
      </div>

      <div id="Location" class="tabcontent">
          <h2>Location</h2>
      </div>

      <div id="Transportation" class="tabcontent">
          <h2>Transportation</h2>
      </div>

      <div id="Amenities" class="tabcontent">
          <h2>Amenities</h2>
      </div>

      <div id="HouseRules" class="tabcontent">
          <h2>House Rules</h2>
      </div>

      <div id="TermsAndConditions" class="tabcontent">
          <h2>Terms And Conditions</h2>
      </div>

      <div id="Contact" class="tabcontent">
          <h2>Contact</h2>
      </div>

      <div id="Partners" class="tabcontent">
          <h2>Partners</h2>
      </div>



</div>


    </header>
  <!-- Navigation End -->
<div class="container">
    <div id="ellipse" class="ellipse_left">
      <img src="assets/ellipse.svg" alt="ellipse" width="400" height="400"/>
    </div>
    <img class="masquarade_events" src="assets/masquarade_events.png" alt="Masquarade Events" width="125" height=""/>
<div class="content">

    <p class="date">25 mei 2019</p>
    <p class="location">Hennemeeuwis Neerpelt</p>
    <h1>Masquarade Classix </h1>
    <ul class="lineup">
        <li>Nina Kraviz</li>
        <li>Recondite</li>
        <li>Mind Against</li>
        <li>Âme</li>
        <li>Vince Watson</li>
        <li>Kölsch</li>
        <li>Rodriguez Jr. </li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
<div class="clear"></div>

    <a href="#" class="button white">Buy Tickets</a>
    <a href="#" class="button black">More Information</a>

</div>
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```